# debian ssh connection refused after update reboot

Tags: ssh

Locked out with SSH from server after a Debian Jessie update and reboot(connection refused).
No websites came backup after reboot but can ping the server.
Can get to the server with host's Ubuntu Rescue via SSH, however at a loss what to do after mounting the boot disk. Logs don't appear to show anything, but am still looking.
There was an SSL certs problem after the updates, which was trying to fix before the server went dead and I decided to reboot.
Any docs or pointers as to what to check to get server back by using the Rescue mode?

Comment: Assuming you use VMware, hyperV or any other virtualization thingy: What does the Console tell you?

Comment: Not using any virtualisation thingy, and no logs since the original reboot.

Comment: So you are able to access the server?

Comment: Yes with Ubuntu Rescue OS, have mounted the boot disk searched logs, etc... in /mnt/

Comment: But are you able to boot the system?

Comment: Nope looks like boot config is broken as zero logs get written

Comment: You should change the question and the title to match the problem

Answer (score 0):

As no error logs had been written since the original reboot after software upgrades using the Rescue OS was pretty useless in diagnosing a problem.
By getting access to KVM and watching the reboot from the console seeing that it failed at a network issue, bypassing and continuing with the boot.
Although the problem of why the network error occurred on reboot is yet to be found, brought the server back up online from the KVM console by checking 'ip a' to show the network interfaces and address, then brought it up with 'ifup eth0' and was able to access by SSH, and all sites came back.

Comment: "Nope looks like boot config is broken as zero logs get written – tjcham 18 hours ago"